Cannot send topic to ActiveMQ Artemis: Unable to validate user
I am trying to get ActiveMQ Artemis running locally on my machine.
I have created a little program (that is started in a Spring Boot app) that creates a JMS ConnectionFactory to ActiveMQ Artemis, creates a topic, and then sends a message on the topic.
public void send() throws Exception {

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();

    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
    connectionFactory.setUser("artemis");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("artemis");

    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);

    Topic myTopic = new ActiveMQTopic("myTopic");

    System.out.println("before");

    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(myTopic, "my message", m -> {
        m.setStringProperty("test", "test");
        return m;
    });

    System.out.println("after");
}

In my docker-compose file, I am starting the Artemis container based on configuration that looks like this :
  akom-activemq-artemis:
    image: apache/activemq-artemis
    ports:
      - "61616:61616"

When I run my program I get an exception that looks like this:
before
after
13:34:01.489 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-172.17.192.1] WARN  o.s.b.actuate.jms.JmsHealthIndicator - JMS health check failed
jakarta.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /172.18.0.1:48222. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:558)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:450)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:308)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:256)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionChannel(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1402)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionInternal(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:733)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSession(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection.authorize(ActiveMQConnection.java:650)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:933)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:291)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:286)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:352)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.getConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:327)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:242)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jms.JmsHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(JmsHealthIndicator.java:51)

If I look at the Docker log then I see that the messages comes through, and the same error message is displayed as from in my program:
2024-05-04 11:22:15,575 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8161
2024-05-04T11:22:15.575723223Z 2024-05-04 11:22:15,575 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console/jolokia
2024-05-04T11:22:15.575744578Z 2024-05-04 11:22:15,575 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console
2024-05-04T11:23:34.101125937Z 2024-05-04 11:23:34,100 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222216: Security problem while authenticating: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /172.18.0.1:34938. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable

Why is this happening? Haven't I already set my username as "artemis"? Why does it say that it is "null"?

Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository?

Your title says, "Cannot send topic to ActiveMQ Artemis..." However, your question says, "If I look at the Docker log then I see that the messages comes through..." These statements appear to contradict each other. Are you able to send a message to the topic or not?

The fact that your application is able to send the message indicates that it is, in fact, using the proper credentials.
The AMQ229031 error that is reported in the broker's log is no doubt the same as the AMQ229031 error reported by the org.springframework.boot.actuate.jms.JmsHealthIndicator from Spring Boot. I'm not sure where this Spring Boot component looks for its configuration, but it needs to use the same credentials as your application is using. Right now it apparently isn't using any credentials which is why the broker is reporting that is receiving a null username.
